# What is the origin of Russian suffix -шк-?

Tags: история-языка, социолингвистика

What is the origin of diminitive suffix *-шк-* for personal names (like *Антошка, Машка, Мишка, Ивашка*)?

Comment: It may be way off, but [Swedish has a suffix "-erska"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-erska) (pronounced "эшка") which transforms verbs to nouns that represent the corresponding female occupation, may be somewhat related.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: the Swedish suffix is apparently a combination of the suffixes cognate to Modern English *-er/-re* and *-ess* ("sorceress", "mistress" etc.)

Answer (score 6):

It's a combination of *-Vх-* (*Антон > Антоха, Илья > Илюха*) and diminutive *-к-*  (< **-ьк*) (*Тоня > Тонька, Маша > Машка*), affected by palatalization: **-хьк- > -шк-*.

Comment: Перечитываю - и не понимаю, Иван - Иванка - Ивашка вписывается в теорию или нет?

Comment: @akaRem: which "theory"?

Answer (score 1):

This *is* complicated. This suffix is composed.

Here is small example from one (http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5310&0a0=2) dictionary:

Good luck, this can keep you busy for an evening.

> 1. Неодинаковы по степени продуктивности образования с уничижительным суффиксом разговорной речи -шк(а). Суффикс -шк(а) с этимологической
>      точки зрения составной. Он включает в себя уменьшительно-ласкательный
>      суффикс -к-, но облекает его оттенками фамильярного пренебрежения.
>      Например: "Вошел старичок низенький и толстенький, из породы людей,
>      называемых коротышками или карандашами" (Тургенев, "Затишье"). В
>      суффиксе -шк(а), кроме суффикса -к-, этимологически различаются разные
>      экспрессивные суффиксы, содержащие звук ш и восходящие к суффиксам
>      -их-, -ух-, -ах-. Среди слов общего рода, оканчивающихся на -шк(а), кроме -ишк(а), выделяются еще два непродуктивных типа:
>
>    1) слова с суффиксом -ушк(а): болтушка, вертушка и т. п.; этот суффикс соотносится с суффиксами лица -ун, -унья (ср. также слова на
>      -уха) и присоединяется к глагольным основам; 2) слова с суффиксом -ашк(а): замарашка, побирашка, старикашка и т. д. (суффикс -ашк(а) частью соотносителен с суффиксом -ах(а), частью с -ан). Ср. у Л.
>      Толстого в "Крейцеровой сонате": "Про себя я думал, что я милашка, что
>      я вполне нравственный человек".
>
>    1. Все теснее сливаются с категорией личных слов на -а презрительно-уничижительные формы с суффиксами -ишк(а) и -онк(а):
>         мальчишка, актеришка, фанфаронишка, хвастунишка, старичишка, мужичонка
>         (51).
>
>       Ср.: "И вот только что показался этот скверный князишка, этот дрянной идиотишка, и все опять взбаламутилось" (Достоевский, "Идиот").
>
>       Образования с этими суффиксами свойственны преимущественно разговорной речи. В формах мужского рода продуктивен суффикс -ишк(а),
>         в формах женского рода -онк(а).

And even that is only scratching a surface. Sometimes -шк- comes from -жк- which comes from -г- (). Each example of шк can have it's own story tracing to different languages and ages.

You can also google "общий род".